# Mysql query taking too much time

Tags: mysql

I have problem related to mysql database. i am linux webserver admin and i am facing a problem with a  mysql query. The database is very small. I tried to track in logs and found that a query is taking minimum 5 sec to respond . The first page of site is coming from the database. Client are using cms. when the server gets some number of hits database server starts to give response very slowly and wait time increases from 5 sec to several seconds.

I checked slow query logs

```
{
Query_time: 11.480138  Lock_time: 0.003837 Rows_sent: 921  Rows_examined: 3333

SET timestamp=1346656767;
SELECT `Tender`.`id`,
    `Tender`.`department_id`,
    `Tender`.`title_english`,
    `Tender`.`content_english`,
    `Tender`.`title_hindi`,
    `Tender`.`content_hindi`,
    `Tender`.`file_name`,
    `Tender`.`start_publish`,
    `Tender`.`end_publish`,
    `Tender`.`publish`,
    `Tender`.`status`,
    `Tender`.`createdBy`,
    `Tender`.`created`,
    `Tender`.`modifyBy`,
    `Tender`.`modified`
FROM `mcms_tenders` AS `Tender`
WHERE `Tender`.`department_id` IN ( 31, 33, 32, 30 );
}
```

Every line in the log is same only there is diff in Query time.
Is there any way tweak the performance?

**Update:** Here is the `EXPLAIN` result:

```
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-‌-----+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----‌​--+-------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | Tender | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 3542 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----‌​--+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

client is saying they are using Index so i run the command to check the indexing.

I got following output. Does It means they are using Indexing.

+--------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+--------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| mcms_tenders |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |        4264 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
+--------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+

Comment: Try to use EXPLAIN and check if the query is using indexes etc.

Comment: use `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` instead. Gives you more information.

Comment: @ j0nes @ Rene Pot+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Tender | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 3542 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Comment: @ j0nes @ Rene Pot Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to tweak the performance of a query like this is to create an index on department_id.

However, this assumes that Tenders is actually a table and not a view.  You should confirm this, since the problem may be in a view.

Also, from what you describe the issue may be the connection from the server to the end users.  I would try running the query locally on the server (or checking the execute time strictly on the server) to see if the query is really taking that long.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff. It was taking same time if I run it on local server.Although i have increased the query cache size. and it resolved the problem. Also i will tell the client to use indexing wherever it will be possible. Thanks Very much

Answer (score 0):

"*when the server gets some number of hits*"

Define 'some number'. It makes sense that reading the database is slower when it is more heavily used. Also, MySQL has a query cache that is fully invalidated when changes are made to the data. So every time someone inserts, deletes or modifies a record in this table, the next queries will be slower because the table date is still uncached.

But 11 seconds for a query like this is very slow, so either the load is way too high, the hardware insufficient or broken or your database lacks indexes (I always forget to mention that at first, because I assume adding indexes to be a second nature for anyone working with databases).

Comment: number varies from 253 to 521.if I check the process list all running queries are same like i pasted above no diff in any query. I dont know why mysql query cache is not working. it is sure that no one is modifying and only select queries are working. Since I am not a developer , could you please suggest what exactly we can do

Comment: @ GolezTrol Hard ware is good as its configuration is 48 core cpu and 64 GB RAM.although others DATABASES of other shared hosting sites are running well.

Comment: Shared hosting makes it tough. Could be a million databases running on that server. How would you know? But check the indexes first. They query itself is simple as can be, but since you use `department_id` in the `where` clause, an index on that column may seriously speed up the query. Only start looking elsewhere if that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @ Golez the query cahe was enabled but it was set to 0 . I increased the size upto 2gb and it worked for me. Thanks for the helps and hints.